# Is there a particular order to doing reflections when there is an inverse reflection (about the line y=x) involved?

Tags: graphing-functions, transformation, inverse-function, reflection

For example, the original function would be y = f(x) and the transformed would be x = -f(y)

If an x-intercept on the original graph was (-2,0) depending on which function was done first, the resulting y-intercept on the reflected graph can be (0,-2) or (0,2).

Also, with the graph of x = -f(y) would the reflection be around the x-axis? or the y-axis?

I had a few other questions where it seemed like for inverse graphs an x = -f(y) would indicate a reflection about the y-axis and x = f(-y) would indicate a reflection about the x-axis

Comment: If you are reflecting the graph about y=x, the function y=f(x) changes to x=f(y)

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I was wondering about the case where you add a horizontal or vertical reflection as well. Which one you would do first if you were just given x = f(-y) for example.

Comment: So, you want to know how reflection changes the function? Shall I write an answer on that?

Comment: Sure, what I would really like to know is if you are given x=-f(y). When you are doing the graph, do you do the inverse reflection first or the reflection about the y-axis?

Answer (score 0):

For any curve $y=f(x)$, by reflection, we can make the following transformations.

[image]

Let this be the graph of $y=f(x)$

### Transformations

- $x\to {-x}$ is reflection about y-axis and gives us the graph of $y=f(-x)$

[image]

- $y\to -y$ is reflection about x-axis and gives us the graph of $y=-f(x)$

[image]

- $x\to y$ and $y\to x$ is reflection about $x=y$ line and gives us the graph of $x=f(y)$

[image]

- $x\to -y$ and $y\to -x$ is reflection about $x=-y$ line and gives us the graph of $-x=f(-y)$

[image]

---

Now, moving on to your question, to transform $y=f(x)\to x=-f(y)$, We could do the following changes
$$y=f(x)\to x=f(y)$$
$$x=f(y)\to -x=f(y)\implies x=-f(y)$$
So, first take reflection about $y=x$ then refelect it about y-axis.

[image]

I hope this lefts no doubts remaining. Cheers!